# centos6.3 The free command memory and top command statistics do not match

Tags: linux, centos

On Centos linux 6.3 I'm running free -m and it shows nearly all 2g used

**Note: buffers/cached is very small**

```
[root@nsdlicense ops]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1877       1736        141          0          6         23
-/+ buffers/cache:       1706        170
Swap:            0          0          0
```

But at the same time in top and enter M I cannot see any processes using all this memory:

```
top - 09:45:01 up 1 day, 23:59,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 112 total,   2 running, 110 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.8%us,  1.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1922620k total,  1778904k used,   143716k free,     6900k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    23564k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                               
 2639 apache    20   0 1722m 265m 3588 S  0.0 14.1   2:20.72 httpd                                                                                                                                 
 6246 apache    20   0 1530m  56m 3576 S  0.0  3.0   2:40.17 httpd                                                                                                                                 
 2564 apache    20   0 1530m  42m 3616 S  0.3  2.3   1:35.79 httpd                                                                                                                                 
 1641 mysql     20   0  818m  31m 2448 S  0.0  1.7   8:54.25 mysqld                                                                                                                                
 8895 apache    20   0  881m  29m 6496 S  0.0  1.6   0:25.66 httpd                                                                                                                                 
27060 root      20   0 28824 3052 2240 S  0.3  0.2   0:03.14 sshd                                                                                                                                  
21110 root      20   0 28716 2836 2176 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.12 sshd                                                                                                                                  
27460 root      20   0 28444 2692 2176 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.04 sshd                                                                                                                                  
 1179 root      20   0  165m 2004 1132 S  0.0  0.1   2:30.19 vmtoolsd                                                                                                                              
27062 root      20   0  105m 1996 1536 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.08 bash                                                                                                                                  
27075 root      20   0  105m 1984 1544 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 bash                                                                                                                                  
 1312 root      20   0 88788 1956  488 S  0.0  0.1   0:16.80 httpd                                                                                                                                 
27468 root      20   0 27732 1776 1352 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sftp-server                                                                                                                           
21133 root      20   0 27732 1708 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sftp-server                                                                                                                           
21127 root      20   0 27732 1684 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 sftp-server                                                                                                                           
21114 root      20   0 27732 1636 1236 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 sftp-server
```

I also tried this [ps mem script](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py) but it onlt shows about 430MB memory being used.

```
[root@nsdlicense ops]# ./ps_mem.py 
 Private  +   Shared  =  RAM used       Program

 96.0 KiB +  48.0 KiB = 144.0 KiB       sleep
264.0 KiB +  15.5 KiB = 279.5 KiB       mysqld_safe
316.0 KiB +  30.5 KiB = 346.5 KiB       auditd
332.0 KiB +  23.0 KiB = 355.0 KiB       init
496.0 KiB +  51.0 KiB = 547.0 KiB       mingetty (6)
508.0 KiB +  97.0 KiB = 605.0 KiB       top
632.0 KiB +  36.5 KiB = 668.5 KiB       crond
292.0 KiB + 615.5 KiB = 907.5 KiB       udevd (3)
  1.2 MiB +  49.0 KiB =   1.3 MiB       rsyslogd
  1.6 MiB +  86.0 KiB =   1.6 MiB       vmtoolsd
  1.2 MiB + 935.5 KiB =   2.1 MiB       bash (3)
  2.4 MiB +   1.2 MiB =   3.6 MiB       sshd (4)
  4.7 MiB +   1.1 MiB =   5.8 MiB       sftp-server (12)
 31.4 MiB + 128.0 KiB =  31.5 MiB       mysqld
375.6 MiB +   5.0 MiB = 380.5 MiB       httpd (5)
---------------------------------
                        430.2 MiB
=================================
```

Comment: See https://www.linuxatemyram.com/.

Comment: Used and free actually match. Shared memory calculation is done badly in Linux.

Comment: @terdon thank you for you answer , I've already checked the website ( linuxatemyram.com), but the buffers/cached for free command is very small. I don't know where my memory is.